# How did the roots of European knightly culture transfer from ancient Iran to European Middle Ages?

Tags: middle-ages, iran

I have come across a reference in a German [guide book](https://www.stefan-loose.de/buecher/asien/iran/) on Iran that suggests the roots of knightly culture in European Middle Ages may be found in the Sassanian Empire (224 to 651 AD; [translation](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Ein%20Element%20des%20Sassanidenreichs%20fand%20durch%20die%20Araber%20Jahrhunderte%20sp%C3%A4ter%20%C3%BCber%20Mauretanien%20Eingang%20nach%20Europa%3A%20die%20Ritterkultur.%20Die%20Sassaniden%20pflegten%20bereits%20Minnedienst%2C%20Turniere%20und%20einen%20Ehrenkodex%20-%20eben%20alles%2C%20was%20auch%20nach%20europ%C3%A4ischem%20Verst%C3%A4ndnis%20zum%20Rittertum%20geh%C3%B6rte.) courtesy of Google Translate with one correction):

> One element of the Sassanian Empire found its way into Europe through
>   Mauritania centuries later: knightly culture. The Sassanids already
>   maintained [courtly love], tournaments and a code of honor - everything that
>   was also part of knighthood according to European understanding.

Assuming that this is an accepted view among historians, how did the transfer occur (in more detail) and which historian (or school of historians) first pointed out this link? Presumably some traces must also exist in Muslim culture for it must have served as "vector" via Mauritania and presumably Spain, so what would such evidence be?

Comment: You are asking about the [_Aswaran_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aswaran) (I believe). I thought I could answer this (quickly) but the long list of end-notes is not enticing! Not for me anyways. But you might like it.

Comment: "Sasanian cavalry tactics were adopted by the Romans, Arabs, and Turks." ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_of_the_Sasanian_Empire)), so a few possibilities. Other relevant info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtly_love#Andalusian_and_Islamic_influence) perhaps. I think "through Mauritania" is meant literally, ie the road they travelled passed though Mauretania.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "*knightly culture*". Feudalism? Poppycock; it first developed under Charles Martel beginning prior to the Battle of Tours. What else then?

Comment: Let's keep it civil.....

Comment: A certain code of honor for society elite and the elite warriors was pretty common in every ancient and medieval society, often deeply rooted in the relevant religious values. Tournaments, etc was also pretty common in many places. While I do not deny that different cultures may have borrowed specific practices from others or inspired shifts in value systems (admiring the enemy), I think stating one would be root to the other is a massive overstatement.

Comment: (note-to-self: 3 rapid close votes on a question like this; current comments and answers just shot-from-the-hip speculations or pointers into Wikipedia; history SE apparently has seen better days; I'll abstain from downvoting myself, will instead vote with my feet -- sadly and again :)

Comment: @Greg: Exactly.  Compare the "knightly" culture of the Japanese samurai for a parallel development with no significant contact.

Comment: Court romance literature was developed in poiters in the 12th century. Poiters received a lot of traffic as a pilgrimage route to Iberia, so there was some exchange.

Comment: @Drux: Why? The question, as is, seems badly flawed by assuming that there WAS a transfer (rather than parallel development), and asking how it took place.  Needs some supporting evidence - and in all likelihood, finding that evidence would go a long way towards explaining how the transfer happened.

Comment: @jamesqf With all due respect, I do not agree: (1) I'm saying the reference "suggests"; (2) I'm citing a reference (admittedly not a scholarly work by a historian but a published guide book); (3) I am stating "assuming that this is an accepted view among historians ...". (Maybe the formulation in the last sentence could be improved for I am not a native speaker. What I mean is that "If the assumption is correct ...", not "I am already assuming ... hence ...") IMHO all of this does not clearly sum up to an "IF" rather than a "WAS". But anyway, thanks for bringing this up in a civilized manner.

Comment: Complaining about Wikipedia - bringing a tourist guide book as the main reference. Complaining about shallow, general answers  - not able himself/herself detail what specifically means by "knightly culture". Blaming everyone for interpreting the question exactly as it means in English, instead "what was the unspoken intent" and yet unable to fix it even when it is explicitly pointed out ... history SE apparently has seen better days.